# Jenkins tries to launch tools/emulator instead of emulator/emulator (Android Emulator Plugin)

Tags: android, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, android-emulator-plugin

I'm trying to set up Jenkins UI tests, and it fails on running emulator command, which was moved from `{$ANDROID_SDK}/tools/emulator` to `{$ANDROID_SDK}/emulator/emulator` in one of android sdk tools update.

I'm not sure why: the Android Emulator Plugin is in version 3.0 which should already use emulator/emulator path. Jenkins ver. 2.204.1

```
[android] Erasing existing emulator data...
$ /var/lib/android/tools/emulator -ports 5724,5725 -report-console tcp:5825,max=60 -avd pixel-2-api28 -wipe-data -no-window
FATAL: Cannot run program "/var/lib/android/tools/emulator": error=2, No such file or directory
java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I've found this issue https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-48787 which is other way around, indicating that 3.0 should use emulator/emulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question - It's an issue with Android Emulator Plugin 3.0 not working with new "Command line tools only" sdk package. I used it on my build server, which obviously sound like something to choose for a build server in comparison to full Android Studio package.

The issue is about how the plugin checks tools versioning, it looks for a property named `Pkg.Revision` in file {$ANDROID_SDK}/tools/source.properties.

For "command line tools" it looks like this:

```
Pkg.Revision=1.0
Pkg.Path=cmdline-tools;1.0
Pkg.Desc=Android SDK Command-line Tools
```

For earlier sdks it looks like e.g this:

```
Pkg.UserSrc=false
Pkg.Revision=26.1.1
Platform.MinPlatformToolsRev=20
Pkg.Dependencies=emulator
Pkg.Path=tools
Pkg.Desc=Android SDK Tools
```

The plugin checks if version is higher than 25.3 ([AndroidSdk.java:161](https://github.com/jenkinsci/android-emulator-plugin/blob/b9dba3d89d7729a835aeebbf3449b57dd0072c67/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/android_emulator/sdk/AndroidSdk.java#L161)), which for command line tools is obviously not.

I'll post a bug report, and I'll update here if I'll find a workaround.

Comment: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-61782 issue report